# How to append decales to animated object in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, decal

Please help me to understand, how to append decales (marks of blows of the sword or marks of bullets) to animated objects.

1) I thought that it should be gameobject, which i appending to collision gameobject (in contact.point), but in this case decale object not animated. It works only if i append it to "bone", but for me it looks strange, i think it's not good.

2) May be it should be texture decales? In this case could me help somebody (How to) ? Should be special decal shader (i tried to use it, but without sucess)?

Please help me with searching good solution.

I am using Unity 2019.

Comment: If your mesh is skinned, I can see how it wouldn't look good, as the mesh is weighted and the decal is not. If you go with 2, what sort of problems did you run into?

Comment: I don't know how append second texture with small decale (first - it's original texture) , and manage decale position on surface :(